# How to find all files except with PNG, JPG extension?

Tags: find

I want to find all files in `/var/www` excluding files with `.php, .html, .png, .jpg` extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `find /var/www/ \( ! -name "*.php" -a ! -name "*.html"  -a ! -name "*.png" -a ! -name "*.jng" \)`

Comment: You can skip the `-a` (since it's the assumed default) and the parenthesis: `find /var/www/ ! -name "*.php" ! -name "*.html" ! -name "*.png" ! -name "*.jpg"`

Comment: One tiny problem, this will also search for directories, which I don't need. How to exclude from search dir?

Comment: Add the predicate `-type f`

Comment: @IanC.   Indeed you can. I just put the params and the `-a` for clarity