# How to find any file other than a particular extension in a folder

Tags: bash, find

I have a folder with mix up of different extension (`.sh .txt .pdb`). I want to find out all the files other than `pdbqt`

I know that I can locate pdbqt within the folder using the following code

```
find -name "*.pdbqt" -type f
```

But I want all the files not matching this to be found out. Generally `!` helps with this. Where to put that `!` here? Or if there is any other elegant solution?

Comment: Related: [How to find all files except with PNG, JPG extension?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336467/how-to-find-all-files-except-with-png-jpg-extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` goes before the test you want to negate:

```
find ! -name "*.pdbqt" -type f
```

Note that many implementations of `find` require the starting path to be specified ([as required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)):

```
find . ! -name "*.pdbqt" -type f
```

The negation only applies to the closest expression, so `-type f` isn’t negated here. To apply a negation to multiple expression, use parentheses (as determined by the precedence order).